# rspec expect redirect_to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Sometimes new (very DRY) rspec syntax makes me crazy...

Rspec v 2.14.1

```
describe "POST create" do
  subject { post :create, contractor: valid_params }

  context "by user" do
    before { sign_in @legal.user }

    it "contractor successful created" do
      expect { subject }.to redirect_to(contractor_path(assigns(:contractor).id))
```

I have error & question here:

```
 NoMethodError: # :contractor variable not defined
   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems that `expect` take an operator before controller method `post` executes, because I try to raise this method.

My code:

```
def create
  @contractor = Contractor.restrict!(current_accreditation).new(permitted_params) # TODO move to the IR::Base
  if @contractor.save
    current_accreditation = @contractor.create_legal!(user: current_user) # TODO legal create
    redirect_to(@contractor)
  else
    render(:new)
  end
end
```

Secondly, why I have an error when try

```
expect(subject).to ...
```

Why `{}` works, but `()` no? In relish docs this method work great: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda unrelated but I've found the following helpful:

- Use `expect {}` when you want to test before/after of whatever's in the block. eg. `expect { subject } to change(User, :count)` - you want to check the count before, then after, to work out the difference and see if it actually changed.
- Use `expect ()` to verify the outcome of a block, eg. that a redirect occurred, or something got assigned, etc.

Your test with the `assigns(:contractor)` doesn't work because you're using the `{}` notation - so it's trying to work out the `assigns(:contractor).id` both before and after evaluating the subject (and of course, before the subject, it doesn't exist).

Comment: It help with several tests (there are many tests), but it seems `it { expect{subject}.to change(controller, :current_accreditation).from(@legal).to(assigns(:contractor).legal) }` take `@contractor` in the start too. Is there any way to avoid that?